# What is the difference between NFC integrated controller and customized firmware version?

Tags: embedded, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

I am looking at NXP's NFC solutions and I am wondering how much work separates between controller with integrated firmware(IF) and customizable firmware(CF) versions. My basic understanding is IF requires an OS like like Linux to run the application code and CF has application code on it. 
I want to use another Cortex-M MCU to drive the application and I want to know whether I can get by without using a Host OS in both cases. Of course, I will be writing application code in the host MCU. All I want is to get the NFC information passed on to host MCU with minimum effort.

http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/nfc-and-reader-ics/nfc-controller-solutions:MC_1429876594926

Can I use NFC Reader Library without a host OS ?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly pointed out, the difference is where your application runs.
You don't necessarily need a host with Linux or any other high-level operating system for your application though.

The main difference is that -- depending on your application -- customizable-firmware devices might suffice and hence lower the cost of your product. However, you're pretty much locked-in to use that specific device and will have cost in porting your application to another device.

Integrated-firmware devices speak a standardized protocol, NFC Controller Interface ([spec here](https://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Controller%20Interface%20(NCI)%20Technical%20Specification.pdf%20NCI%20Specification)). This means you will need some kind of additional host processor where your code runs, but this makes your application more flexible, because you're not bound to the specific NFC device. You can redesign your product using another NCI-capable device and control it in the same way.

The NFC Reader Library is available for Linux and for NXP's own LPC1xxx series of microcontrollers (FreeRTOS-based apparently) and uses I²C or SPI for NCI transport. The hardware abstraction layer can be adapter for other micocontrollers to [AN11308](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11308.pdf).

When using a customizable-firmware device, you will have to interact with the integrated IP blocks through memory-mapped I/O. There are separate software development kits available when you check on the device page as well as the NFC cockpit, which helps configuring these devices correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot FRob. Can I assume customizable-firmware device get the advantage of NXP's firmware on integrated devices (NFC cockpit) plus the freedom to add application code? My requirement includes two more I/O devices and I don't think I can use customizable-firmware device version. Either way, I can use the NFC Reader Library  in both cases as long as the extra MCU is one of LPC1xxx series.

Comment: If you end up going with a custom fw device, you would need to emulate the NCI protocol in order to use the NFC Reader Library on an external IC. The easiest route is to go with integrated firmware and use the library, however, if your needs are satisfied with adding two peripherals via SPI/I²C/UART, then you could use the custom FW line of devices. You should probably write down your requirements and go from there... Can't really help you in detail with your product here.

Comment: FRob, Thanks again. I am reviewing the datasheet to see whether the I/O present will work with external devices such as GSM module etc. I also want to run TCP/IP stack for upstream communication. Going through the software manual and documentation. Your answer is really helpful.